# easiest approach to calculate basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find basis vectors of the following space:
$$W=\{(x_2,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | x_1+2x_2-x_3+x_4=0 \}$$
What is the eastiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose three of your variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ as parameters and solve for the remaining variable. You can choose those three variables freely, such as one of them $1$ and the others $0$, and use those as basis vectors.

In your case, we have $x_4=-x_1-2x_2+x_3$. Choosing $x_1=1,x_2=0,x_3=0$ you get $x_4=-1$. So our first basis vector is $(1,0,0,-1)$. Continue in this way to find two other basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that satisfy $x_1+2x_2-x_3+x_4=0$. Any and only 4-vectors that can be expressed in the form

$$
\left[\begin{array} {}-2x+y-z\\x\\y\\z\end{array}\right]
$$
will satisfy this requirement, for some $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. We can then decompose this vector into three basis vectors:
$$
\left[\begin{array} {}-2x+y-z\\x\\y\\z\end{array}\right]=x\left[\begin{array} {}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right]+y\left[\begin{array} {}1\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right]+z\left[\begin{array} {}-1\\0\\0\\1\end{array}\right]
$$
in which the three vectors are basis vectors.